# How I can determine which key is pressed on keyboard? C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, keyboard, keycode

How I can determine which key is pressed on keyboard in C++ using WINAPI?

I try to use `GetAsyncKeyState`, but it work just for exactly one key, and I need to choose which one, but I need to get keyсode to it be send over tcp.

Comment: If you read the man page for `GetAsyncKeyState` you will see it [links you to GetKeyboardState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Depends on whether you are in a console app or a GUI app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over every character and try each one:

```
for (char i = 32; i < 127; i++)
    if (GetAsyncKeyState (i))
         /* Do whatever you want with that character */;
```

In the example I loop just from ' ' to '~', modify it as you want.

Comment: It's `GetAsyncKeyState`, with a capital `G`. But you don't need to call it in a loop anyway, since there is [GetKeyboardState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299.aspx) that returns the key states for the entire keyboard.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, but `GetKeyboardState` matches `GetKeyState`, which has different semantics from `GetAsyncKeyState`. As to which semantics the asker needs, I don't think that we can be sure.